# Filter orders by Purchase Order in WooCommerce admin orders list page

Tags: woocommerce, filtering, purchase-order

I want to customize admin order list page in Woocommerce where I can search the products using Purchase Order number.

I am new to WooCommerce, And I want to customize admin order list page. So basically I to create a search box using Purchase order as a filter.

Now in admin order listing page, I want to show a Purchase order column too. How I can do this?

I searched a lot, and there is nothing I can found about this problem. Hope someone here can help me.
TIA